# can I move the Launcher to the right side? left side is too distracting to me

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)

I am ready to stop using unity because I find having the Launcher on the left side too distracting. I use Windows 7 Taskbar on the right side of the screen and really like this. But I can't stand having OS controls on my left margin.

How do I move the Launcher to the right side? I'm not going to be able to keep using Unity if the launcher has to be on the left side.