# Moving unity to the right side

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher)
>   [How can I move the launcher to the right side of the screen? I am left-handed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89725/how-can-i-move-the-launcher-to-the-right-side-of-the-screen-i-am-left-handed)

I know it happens when I'm changing the language to Hebrew but I still want it in English.

How do I do this? If I can't is there any schedule for this feature being added?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33605/can-i-move-the-unity-launcher http://askubuntu.com/questions/31494/can-i-move-the-launcher-to-the-right-side-left-side-is-too-distracting-to-me ;)